# About Legacy Application Classes 12 to Ojdbc6 migration in jdev9.0

Tags: java

Currently I am working with a legacy application which uses classes12 and jdevoper 9.0 and java 1.4.  I wanted to upgrade java to 1.6 and OJDBC6 with Jdev 9.0 .
But Jdev use BC4 libraries which are also old one. I had changed my java version to 1.6 and updated  classes12 to ojdbc6. but after that I was facing build issue as BC4j lib also have some connection with it.
after updating bcj lib with adfm jar I am getting below issue. Could any one please suggest any minimal changes to work my application to work

Currently java 1.4 oracle 11g DB and Jdev 9.0 classe12 and I want
 java 1.6 oracle 12c jdev 9.0 ojdbc6

```
SEVERE: { type : AppBundleInfoRT, id : 'en_US-null-null', moRefName : null, appBundleName : null, writable : false, dirty : false, hasMdsConfig : false, appOverrideBundle : null}: Fail to read adf-config.xml
oracle.adf.share.ADFShareException: getMDSInstance error
        at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:104)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.AppBundleInfoRT.readAdfConfig(AppBundleInfoRT.java:341)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.AppBundleInfoRT.loadData(AppBundleInfoRT.java:123)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.AppBundleInfoFactoryRT.createAppBundleInfo(AppBundleInfoFactoryRT.java:83)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.ResourceBundleUtils.getAppBundleInfoUnlocked(ResourceBundleUtils.java:334)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.ResourceBundleUtils.getAppBundleInfo(ResourceBundleUtils.java:325)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.ResourceBundleCacheConfig.getCurrentAppConfig(ResourceBundleCacheConfig.java:109)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.ResourceBundleManagerRT.<init>(ResourceBundleManagerRT.java:84)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.ResourceBundleManager.getResourceBundleManager(ResourceBundleManager.java:183)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.BundleFactory.getMap(BundleFactory.java:86)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.BundleFactory.getBundle(BundleFactory.java:245)
        at oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.BundleFactory.getBundle(BundleFactory.java:206)
        at oracle.jbo.common.StringManager.getStringFromBundle(StringManager.java:582)
        at oracle.jbo.common.StringManager.getStringInternal(StringManager.java:530)
        at oracle.jbo.common.StringManager.getString(StringManager.java:477)
        at oracle.jbo.common.StringManager.getLocalizedString(StringManager.java:305)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c does not support `ojdbc6` as per [What are the Oracle JDBC releases versus JDK versions?](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1) docs. Do note that Oracle 12cR2 strictly requires `ojdbc8` to establish the connection, your current Java 6 setup most likely won't work.

Comment: i do agree. but i am getting this issue while connecting to 11g with ojdbc6 from jdev9

Comment: What is the exact JDBC driver version that you are using? Also, where did you download the JDBC driver from ?

Comment: i am using ojdbc6 and i had downloaded it from oracle site